# how to remove unrecognized hidden character from a string

Tags: c#

I have a WYSIWYG editor, when a user copies and pastes from another different document source, weirdly it adds a question mark while saving it to the database. But, when I debug through the code, copied that string, and preview it in a JSON lint it is seen that it contains some hidden character.

[image]

In the WYSIWYG editor, users may add HTML tags, special characters, punctuation, and different symbols, but I want to remove only those unrecognized spaces? How can I do that?

I tried using the following code, but it removed all whitespace and other characters:

```
string output = new string(input.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Can you find out what that character actually is? It's probably a non-breaking space or a ZWJ or something. Note that you can't just strip out all ZWJ, as that will break some characters (and emoji!)

Comment: yeah it is a space.

Comment: There are many sorts of space. What is the actual character code?

Comment: how to see what character code it is?

Comment: Is it a question mark like �. If so, this is the unicode replacement character that is comonly used to render an unknown character, may be from a different characterset/encoding.

Comment: @aakash e.g. like this: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAAQCYAGAWAChqBGRxi5mgAgGcuBeLgCIAEjAA24iFwDq0cYSEBuNgwBm0GAEMwACy4AKAG5aoXMFwCWeXgEpGAb0ZcXLjgE4DB6xlthbSq6MAL5AA

Comment: while I paste that string to that editor, it is removed automatically.

Comment: What? No. Debug through your code. Look at the string variable which contains your weird characters. You can then use the Immediate or Watch windows to work with that string, e.g. put `string.Join(" ", myString.Select(x => (int)x))` into the Watch window. Or if you know that the weird character is at position 3, you can just put `(int)myString[3]` into the watch window. Or insert some code which prints the integer value of each character in your string to the console / Output window / a log file, and run it. No need to copy or paste anything.

Comment: 60 112 62 8207 69 102 102 101 99 116 105 118 101 32 68 97 116 101 58 38 110 98 115 112 59 60 47 112 62

This is the the output i got, and my input string was: `‏Effective Date: `

Comment: OK, so that 8207 is [U+200F, "RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm). Everything else looks fine. You can strip it out by value if you just want to get rid of it: it's not really adding anything there. Alternatively, you can strip out all characters with have a [Unicode Category of `Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.unicodecategory?view=net-6.0)

Comment: and when I add just `‏Effe`, the output is  `78 101 104 97 32 32 75 65`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the method `.replace()` with and use RegEx as filter in the replace.

More on the `replace()` method : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0

More on RegEX: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0